# Using parent method with subclass variables

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a parent class method in my subclass but it takes always the parent class attributes instead of the subclass attributes..

here the example:

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour{

  protected val = 5;

  public void example(){
    Debug.Log(val);
  }
}

public class Enemy : Character{
  public void Reset(){
    val = 10;
  }
}
```

I get always 5 when I do .example() on a Enemy object...

thanks!

Comment: Does your code compile? No, it doesn't compile. Provide ACTUAL code if you want assistance....

Comment: Have you tried calling `Reset()` first?

Comment: please remove the unity tag, this is related only to unity3d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you ever call `Reset` on `Enemy`?

If you don't `val` will have its default value which is `5`.

Comment: No I don't call Reset, I was thinking that Reset() was a default method called like Start and update, I will try later!

Comment: Reset is a message that Unity calls. But that's used in the Editor. Unity doesn't call Reset at runtime. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html

Comment: actually you can remove Reset() ... well I don't know if you're using it for something else but if not... you can remove it and just have something like:
public class Enemy : Character{
  
    val = 10;

  void Start(){ example();}
}